# Client Connections Count on AWS EFS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-efs

Based on [AWS Documentation,](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/monitoring-cloudwatch.html) Client Connections is:

> The number of client connections to a file system. When using a standard client, there is one connection per mounted Amazon EC2 instance.

Since we have around 10 T3 - EC2 instances running, I would think that ClientConnections would return max of 10.
However, on a normal day, there's around 300 connections and the max we've seen is 1,080 connections.

[image]

I have trouble understanding what exactly is Client Connection count.

- I initially thought 1 EC2 instance = 1 Connection (Since it only
  mounts once, but this doesn't seem to be the case)
- Then I thought, it might be per read/write operation. But looking at the graph at the right - read actually dips (we don't have much writes on our website)

Any help appreciated! I believe I might be missing some core concepts, so please feel free to add them in

Answer (score 0):

Client Connection Count refers to the number of IP Addresses(EFS clients) connecting to EFS mount target on a specific NFS port number eg: NFS port 2049

Resource: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/list-instances-connected-to-efs/